# What does "L" means in Elasticsearch Node status?

Tags: elasticsearch

Bellow is the Node status of my Elasticsearch cluster(please follow the `node.role` column,

```
[root@manager]# curl -XGET http://192.168.6.51:9200/_cat/nodes?v
ip           heap.percent ram.percent cpu load_1m load_5m load_15m node.role master name
192.168.6.54           20          97   0    0.00    0.00     0.00 dim       -      siem03.arif.local
192.168.6.51           34          55   0    0.16    0.06     0.01 l         -      siem00.arif.local
192.168.6.52           15          97   0    0.00    0.00     0.00 dim       *      siem01.arif.local
192.168.6.53           14          97   0    0.00    0.00     0.00 dim       -      siem02.arif.local
```

From [Elasticsearch Documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-nodes.html),

> node.role, r, role, nodeRole
>   (Default) Roles of the node. Returned values include m (master-eligible node), d (data node), i (ingest node), and - (coordinating node only).

So, from the above output, the `dim` means, Data + Master + Ingest node. Which is absolutely correct. But I configured the host `siem00.arif.local` as a coordinating node. But it showed `l` which is not an option described by the documentation.

So what does it mean? It was just `-` before. But after an update (which I have pushed on each of the nodes) it doesn't work anymore and shows `l` in the `node.role`

**UPDATE**:

- All the other nodes except the coordinating node were 1 version back. Now I have updated all of the nodes with exact same version. Now **it works** and here is the output,

```
[root@manager]# curl -XGET http://192.168.6.51:9200/_cat/nodes?v
ip           heap.percent ram.percent cpu load_1m load_5m load_15m node.role master name
192.168.6.53            9          79   2    0.00    0.20     0.19 dilm      *      siem02.arif.local
192.168.6.52           13          78   2    0.18    0.24     0.20 dilm      -      siem01.arif.local
192.168.6.51           33          49   1    0.02    0.21     0.20 l         -      siem00.arif.local
192.168.6.54           12          77   4    0.02    0.19     0.17 dilm      -      siem03.arif.local
```

**Current Version is :**

```
[root@manager]# rpm -qa | grep elasticsearch
elasticsearch-7.4.0-1.x86_64
```

Comment: `node.ml: true` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The built-in roles are indeed `d`, `m`, `i` and `-`, but any plugin is free to define new roles if needed. There's another one called `v` for voting-only nodes.

The `l` role is for Machine Learning nodes (i.e. those with `node.ml: true`) as can be seen in the source code of [`MachineLearning.java`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/d683b2060b1775a517778d7ac28adbe84d524336/x-pack/plugin/ml/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/xpack/ml/MachineLearning.java#L317) in the `MachineLearning` plugin.

Comment: Wow! Great, thanks. I also thought about it but didn’t find any evidence.